# Transformation Matrix for two models

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I have a two matrix representing theoretical and experimental data. Let’s say matrix A of size 872*3 and Matrix B if size 872*3. I want to transform A to B how would I do it.

Comment: There are infinitely many ways to transform data so you'll have to be more specific about what sort of transformation you're looking for.

Comment: So, Matrix A are coordinates of the receptors on the animal and Matrix B is the same but calculated experimentally. I want to do a linear transformation if possible so that I can know where does one value on Matrix A correspond to on Matrix B

Comment: If you want any linear transformation then just add the two matrices together. You could also just subtract one from the other to have a different linear transformation. In fact, as I mentioned before, there are infinitely many ways to perform linear transformations on this data. Without some more information about what you intend the transformation to do there isn't any reason to prefer one over another.